# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when forming list

Tags: c#

I am trying to form a list with the help of multi-dimensional array that should look like this.

```
[validatorKey][counter]
1453          10
1231          12
6431          7
1246          1
1458          2
```

however, I couldn't cope with it. this is my method by the way. and also the array size should be incremented at the very end of the method. I know I should use Array.Resize(ref array, 2); but since my array is multi dimensional, in this case what should be the appropriate method.

```
private int AracaAitSeferSayisiDondur(int pValidatorKey)
{
     int iSeferSayisi = 0;
     int[,] iSeferListesi = (int[,])ViewState["SeferListesi"];
     if (iSeferListesi == null)
     iSeferListesi = new int[1,1];

     bool aynisiVarmi = false;

     for (int i = 0; i < iSeferListesi.Length; i++)
     {
        if (iSeferListesi[i,0] == pValidatorKey)
        {
           aynisiVarmi = true;
           iSeferListesi[i,1]++;
           iSeferSayisi = iSeferListesi[i,1]++;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (!aynisiVarmi)
     {
        int arrayLength = iSeferListesi.Length;
        iSeferListesi[arrayLength--, 0] = pValidatorKey;
        iSeferListesi[arrayLength--, 1] = 1;
        //IN THIS PART ARRAY SIZE SHOULD BE INCREASED
        iSeferSayisi = iSeferListesi[arrayLength--, 1];
     }
     ViewState["SeferListesi"] = iSeferListesi;
     return iSeferSayisi;
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't grow very well. Use a `List<>` or maybe a `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: There is a question involving resizing multi-dimensional arrays [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6539571/704144). I agree with @Henk though, a list or dictionary may suit your needs better than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need sonmething like:

```
// not tested
private int AracaAitSeferSayisiDondur(int pValidatorKey)
{
    var iSeferListesi = (Dictionary<int,int>)ViewState["SeferListesi"];
     if (iSeferListesi == null)
        iSeferListesi = new Dictionary<int,int>;

     int iSeferSayisi;

    if ( iSeferListesi.TryGetValue(pValidatorKey, out iSeferSayisi)
    {
       iSeferSayisi += 1;
       iSeferListesi[pValidatorKey] = iSeferSayisi;
       iSeferSayisi += 1;  // is this OK ??
    }
    else
    {
       iSeferSayisi = 1;
       iSeferListesi[pValidatorKey] = iSeferSayisi;
    }

    ViewState["SeferListesi"] = iSeferListesi;
    return iSeferSayisi;
}
```

The double increment of iSeferListesi (derived from your code) is probably not what you want, without it the if/else logic becomes even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The `Length` proprety returns the total number of elements in the array.

Use the [`GetLength(dimension)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) to get the size of a dimension:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iSeferListesi.GetLength(0); i++)
```

and:

```
int arrayLength = iSeferListesi.GetLength(0);
```

Comment: but I get the error in this part.
`iSeferListesi[arrayLength--, 0] = pValidatorKey;`

Comment: @MehmetBudak: Same there: `int arrayLength = iSeferListesi.GetLength(0);`