# Extend 2D array size?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize multidimensional (2D) array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c)

I have 2D array : myarray[5,6];
And my array is already full. But still, i want to add some more elements in it. 
So , how to extend the size of an array? 
OR
how to declare dynamic 2D array? (Sorry for asking silly question :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `List` of `List`s.

```
List<List<int>> data = new List<List<int>>();

for(int i = 0; i < rowsToAdd; i++)
{
   List<int> newRow = new List<int>();
   for(int j = 0; j < columnsToAdd; j++)
   {
       newRow.Add(j);
   }
   data.Add(newRow);
}
```

Then to add a new row:

```
List<int> nextRow = new List<int>(){0,1,2,3};
data.Add(nextRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.Resize()`:

```
var arr = new int[10];
Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length * 2); // doubles the array size
```

**Update**

Sorry, I just missed 2D:

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c).

Comment: Just for reference, this doesn't change the array at all, it just creates a new, larger, array and copies all of the data from the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are asking for the solution of the wrong problem.
You should not (in most cases) resize your array by hand. Use and generic list (or a generic list of generic lists) as already suggested here

Please, read this rant: [Arrays considered somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)

Consider using generic lists as already suggested by others.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a new array if you need to extend the size. If you look at the right side, you can see an answer.