# How to add data from 1d to 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, jagged-arrays

How can I add an array to another 2D array? For example

```
//change this
array2d = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
//to this
array2d = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
//by adding
array1d = {7,8,9};
```

Is there any better way other than create a new array, which is bigger than the old one, then copy the old array to the array?

Comment: You cannot resize arrays, so the answer is no.

Comment: [Resize multi dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: what are you talking about that you cannot resize and array.. yes you can [Array.Resize Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize)

Comment: You may want to try to use a generic collection such as List<T> instead of an array.

Comment: technically `Array.Resize` allocates a new array. It does not resize the array. It replaces the array with a new one of a different size.

Comment: DJ Kraze, you can use Array.Resize, but not in the context of the question Parman asked.

Comment: He's not asking about simply resizing, he wants to change the number of dimensions on it. And no, @parman, there is no better way. You'll have to create a new one and copy everything from one to the other. Not even ReDim Preserve in VB supports creating new dimensions.

Comment: after reading / looking at what the OP was wanting I misread also `Andre Silva` there is always a better / alternative way to do things especially in a `4GL/5GL` language such as .NET

Comment: @parman: It looks like your problem is resolved. Please don't forget to accept an answer you found most useful, and upvote other relevant answers (on this, and also your previous question).

Comment: @DJKRAZE you should read the sources you provide. It clearly states that Array.Resize allocates a new array. In my opinion that is not resizing.

Comment: Dude I already think you're late to the party on this one.. I think you should read my post comment which makes your response totally useless..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a `List<List<int>>` for something like this, unless you have a reason not to.

The code for it may look something like this:

```
List<List<int>> my2dList = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>()
    {
        1,
        2,
        3
    },
    new List<int>()
    {
        4,
        5,
        6
    },
};
my2dList.Add(new List<int>(){7,8,9});
```

Alternatively, if you really want to limit each column to a length of three, consider using an inner structure with an immutable size (array of size 3, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to use a different data structure, a list of arrays would make this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Extended version of the code snippet posted by @VP. includes the back-conversion from List(List> to Jagged Array using Linq:

```
    // 2d array to List
    List<List<int>> ar2list = new List<List<int>>()
    {
        new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 },
        new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 },
    };

    // adding item to List
    ar2list.Add(new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 });

    // List to Jagged array conversion using Linq
    int[][] _arrConcat = ar2list.Select(Enumerable.ToArray).ToArray();
```

Finally, pertinent to this particular use-case as requested by OP, `int[][]` can be easily converted to `int[,]` with simple `for` loop:

```
array2d = new int[_arrConcat.Length, 3];
for (int i = 0; i<_arrConcat.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        array2d[i, j] = _arrConcat[i][j];
    }
}
```

where `array2d` is the original array with added index/content.

Hope this will help. Best regards,