# How to resize structure array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, resize, 2d, structure

```
struct UurroosterKlasStruct
{
   public int Vak;
   public int Lkr;
}
UurroosterKlasStruct[,] UurroosterKlas;`
```

I need to resize this array later on, but the array.resize function does not seem to work.. I want to change the array to [10,10]. can anyone one put me on my way?

Comment: I think you're experiencing this issue because the array is a 2D array and not a multi-dimensional array. According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6539620/2208058 the array resize functionality treats all arrays as 1-dimensional. That answer also includes a solution.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Resize "Changes the number of elements of a one-dimensional array to the specified new size."

Answer (score 0):

Array's can not be resized once a size is specified. They are fixed at the point you give their size. If you want something dynamic try using something like a List or Dictionary. You would have to create a new array and of larger size and copy existing data into it.

So your code could be like:

```
struct UurroosterKlasStruct
{
   public int Vak;
   public int Lkr;
}
UurroosterKlasStruct[,] UurroosterKlas;`
UurroosterKlas = new UurroosterKlasStruct[10,10];
```

Comment: To clarify once a size is set it is fixed.

Comment: I agree, but that's not what you said.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: Arrays can not be resized. If the size isn't specified then there exists no array, it's just a variable without a value.

Comment: @Guffa you should let msdn know that their link is wrong then.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: What link?

Comment: @Guffa you amuse me.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: What link are you talking about? The link that you posted? In what way would that be wrong? And what would Microsoft do about a link that you posted?

Comment: @Guffa You're serious, right?

Comment: @TigOldBitties: Are you serious? Why do you write comments if you can't tell what you mean by them?

Comment: @Guffa Because for a dude with this much reputation i find it hard to believe you can't get what i'm saying, so you must be trolling.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: When you say that the link is wrong, what do you mean? Do you mean the link that you posted? Do you mean that something on that page is wrong? I can guess what you might mean, should I do that? Are you truly incapable of telling what you mean?

Comment: So you mean that "Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 5);" is not resizing because technically it creates another instance? Are you being condescending or just a jerk? Cause i can't tell.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: So, you were trolling after all... When you said that the link was wrong, you were in fact insinuating that I was wrong. Yes, I mean that calling `Array.Resize` doesn't resize an array, because that's not what the method does. If you read the documentationm it says that *"This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one."*.

Comment: You're just being condescending. I already mentioned it's a new instance, but who cares, for all intents and purposes it's resized to what you need.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: It's you who tried to bash me with Microsoft documentation, but that doesn't work if you don't read it properly. Yes, the method produces an array with the desired size, but it was you who said that it was wrong to say that arrays can't be resized, when it is in fact completely correct.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: It's not "my" definition of resizing. You can call it "resizing" if you like, but Microsoft doesn't.