# How do I resize a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, resize

I want to continuously add a row of 4 values to a 4 dimensional array as long as the user desires it. I can do it with 4 single dimensional arrays but each value has an assigned array of its own which makes the program too long and doesn't look nice.

Comment: It's already there, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: You should not use arrays when you want to "continuously add". Investigate `List<T>`, in as many dimensions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the dimension actively grows, you should use another data type than an array (at least for that dimension).

I would suggest to use a `List<ArrayType[][][]>` (a list of a three-dimensional array). A list is backed by an array and `List` handles resizing. Just call `Add` once you want to add a 'row'.

Comment: I know you use lists but my assignment requires me to use only arrays which is a pain.

Comment: Then you have to resize your array every time you want to add a row, or keep an additional counter where you store the actually last row used. You can size the array at a decent size, to reduce the number of resizes.

Comment: I nkow but how. Array.Resize only works for single dimensional arrays

Comment: Then resize and copy by hand.