# C# in Windows Forms : "Index was outside the bounds of the array" at a try to auto-add new space

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, bounds

I really can't understand where's from this error and how to fix it. 
My idea is to grow the space with 1 every time I read a new object, that's why I use `int m = a.GetLength(0)+1;` 
 `a[m, j] = Convert.ToString(m);` is j=1 which means the number of account which is in fact m, last position from array.
How can I made this works without writing a lot of lines and copy vector in another with +1 line every time I want to add new element?

// "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
// "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in code.exe"

photo with code&error:

[image: photo with code&error]

```
    private void adauga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int m = a.GetLength(0)+1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {   a[m, j] = Convert.ToString(m);
                a[m, j] = textnume.Text;
                a[m, j] = textprenume.Text;
                a[m, j] = textcnp.Text;
                a[m, j] = textserie.Text;
                a[m, j] = textnumar.Text;
                a[m, j] = textdebcre.Text;
                b[m] = Convert.ToInt32(textsuma.Text); } }
```

Where a and b are :
        static string [,]a = new string[1,1];
        static int[] b=new int[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9TuF.png);

Comment: You are using an Object Oriented Language named C#, you should really declare a class for whatever your textboxes represent and then store the instance of this class in a `List<T>` where T are the instances of your class. What is the purpose of these textboxes?

Comment: `int m = a.GetLength(0)+1;` that should be `int m = a.GetLength(0)-1;`, no?

Comment: i'm using textboxes to write names,ci number,the sum from account etc. and then save those in the array

Comment: @TaW no I think she's trying to make the array bigger in this line.
Unfortunately you can not resize a multidimensional array. Thats why  problem occurs; because you are trying to access an index in the array which does not exist. You should solve this problem with objects and lists, I will try to make an example.

Comment: _My idea is to grow the space with 1 everytime i read a new object_ : Arrays will not grow! - Use a List<T> if you want something that can be append to easily! yourList.Add(newItem);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occurs as you are trying to access an entry in the array which does not exist. This is not allowed, and therefore an exception is thrown.

Your array at this point in time has the size you've defined at the first line:

```
static string [,] a= new string [1,1];
```

Which means the only valid entry is at `a[0,0]`. To access other entries you need to explicitly resize the array to the new size you want: [How to resize multidimensional (2D) array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c)

I'm guessing you want to save entries from your application in this array once the user clicks on that button. I'd recommend you solve this problem with objects and `List<T>`, rather than multidimensional arrays:

Create an object which contains the properties you want to save, similar to this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Nume {get; set;}
    public string PreNume {get; set;}
    //your other properties here
}
```

Then create a List to save you objects into. Lists have the advantage to arrays that they can grow even after you've defined them.
The T in List is for an arbitrary class, you can use here the `MyClass` we defined above. So:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Now put it all together:

```
private List<MyClass> _myList = new List<MyClass>();
private void adauga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a myClass Object
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Nume = textnume.Text;
    myClass.PreNume = textprenume.Text;
    //continue here...

    //add it to the list
    _myList.add(myClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, only textdebcre.Text will be in a[m,j] at the end. Second, a is [1,1] and you are trying to access a[1, bigger then 1] so you have an error. Just make a to `new string[1,7]`.