# Resize matrix in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to follow the advices of [How to resize multidimensional (2D) array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c)

However, they do not explain how is the syntax to call the solutions they explained there.

Suppose I have the function,

```
void ResizeArray<T>(ref T[,] original, int newCoNum, int newRoNum)
        {
            var newArray = new T[newCoNum, newRoNum];
            int columnCount = original.GetLength(1);
            int columnCount2 = newRoNum;
            int columns = original.GetUpperBound(0);
            for (int co = 0; co <= columns; co++)
                Array.Copy(original, co * columnCount, newArray, co * columnCount2, columnCount);
            original = newArray;
        }
```

and I want to change the size of a double array [,] myMatrix,

How do I call that function, I have been trying,

```
ResizeArray(myMatrix, 3,3)
```

but I keep getting errors and I don't understand.

The error says:

> Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Program.ResizeArray(ref T[*,*], int, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)

If I google this error, I don't get any answer for this particular problem. Therefore, I need to ask you. This is all the information I can provide, there is really nothing else. I have a matrix 2x2 and I need to resize it to nxn with a changing n. The solution I found is the one I pasted and the error I get is also pasted.

Hope somebody can help.
Regards

Comment: Could you please show how your `myMatrix` is declared? The type argument should be inferred (see the demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/408IVV). By the way you should call the method with `ref` param like `ResizeArray(ref myMatrix, 3, 3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify what `T` is. Assuming `myMatrix` contains elements of type `double`, you need

```
ResizeArray<double>(myMatrix, 3, 3)
```

Comment: This is not necessarily, because the type argument should be inferred from the type of the `myMatrix` (see demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/408IVV). I believe there is something wrong in the way the method is called, therefore we see the error.

Comment: @Bpi: E. Shcherbo is correct though; you should check out why the type cannot be inferred - how do you define the array?