# How do I create a bigger matrix from another?

Tags: java, matrix, methods

I'm having a problem working with matrices. I have a matrix which will hold 3 columns of data and as a starting point 10 rows of data. Each row is an article in a "cash register software" and each column is in order: `{article number, items in stock, article price}`.

As I mentioned, the int[][]articles has to start with the size of [10][3], but have the ability to expand with the help of a method "checkFull". The user will be asked how many articles he/she wants to add and the value will be saved into the variable "noOfArticles". The checkFull() method has to check if the value of articles fits into the article[][] matrix or if it has to create another matrix with the right amount of slots, copy the values from articles[][] and return the new matrix.

The following code is my shot at the problem, does anyone got any ideas how to get this method working properly?

```
public static int[][] checkFull(int[][]articles, int noOfArticles) {
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0; 

    while (i < articles.length)
    {
      if (articles[i][0] == 0)
      {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }

    if ((articles.length - index) < noOfArticles)
    {
      newmat = new int[noOfArticles + articles.length][3];

      for (i = 0; i < articles.length; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < articles[i].length; j++)
        {
          int[][]newmat[i][j] = articles[i][j];
        }
      }
      return newmat;
    }
    
    else
    {
      return articles;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, Java is an object-oriented language. Why don't you create a class which represents the thing you are modeling? For instance, `class Article { int articleNumber; int itemsInStock; int articlePrice; }`. Or is this a homework question requiring you to use a matrix?

Comment: @MCEmperor This is for a homework yes! Otherwise I would use some kind of arraylist etc.

Comment: Check this link out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539571/how-to-resize-multidimensional-2d-array-in-c]